# Problemas al instalar Eclipse en Fedora

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora

tengo años en Ubuntu pero apenas estoy dando mis primeros pasos en Fedora, trabajo mucho con el IDE Eclipse, ya instale el JDK, pero tengo errores al instalar Eclipse, aca les dejo el comando y el error:

> ./eclipse-inst
>
> No protocol specified
> Eclipse Installer: No se puede abrir el visor:
> No protocol specified
> Eclipse Installer: No se puede abrir el visor:
> No protocol specified
> No protocol specified
>
> Eclipse Installer:
> An error has occurred. See the log file
> /opt/eclipse-installer/configuration/1515859028803.log.

He leido en internet algo sobre el archivo XINIT pero no entiendo bien.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad eclipse esta en los repositorios de Fedora. No hay necesidad de instalarlo por aparte.

Para corroborar que esta en tus repositorios puedes usar (desde root):

```
# dnf search eclipse
```

Esto te mostrará una lista con todos los paquetes que llevan eclipse como parte de su nombre (muchos de ellos son plugins de eclipse).

[image: paquetes al buscar la palabra eclipse]

Luego eliges los plugins que necesitas y los listas por ejemplo si quieres instalar el plugin de git y el de herramientas web puedes poner:

```
# dnf install eclipse-webtools-javaee eclipse-jdt eclipse-jgit
```

Por mi parte yo suelo instalar todos los plugins colocando:

```
# dnf install eclipse-*
```

Esto lo hago por que tengo bastante espacio en disco y me molesta ir descargando los plugins conforme los voy necesitando.